# problems turning a list into double for wilcox.test

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to use a list that looks like

```
list <- 0.281097 0.245194 0.172255 0.136205 0.435323 0.431997 0.332863 0.371120 0.428497 0.414634 0.369541 0.303205 0.342573 0.328254 0.358234 0.364887 0.120683 0.118715 0.206876 0.387825 0.059059 0.075471 0.173021 0.359584 0.047235 0.083811 0.159509 0.361754 0.085833 0.162752 0.161182 0.362446 0.043862 0.035496
```

in wilcox.test (btw this list is X-Y so should I make another with all 0s to use for y?)
 but when I try

```
wilcox.test(x=as.integer(unlist(list)))
```

I get "(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

How do I set this up so I can actually get a rank-sum test? I will continue to work on this and If I figure anything out I will post online.
Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: I don't think you've shown us the code you actually ran. For example, did you really try to run that first bit `list <- ...` literally as you've shown it?

Comment: Actually I am a statistics intern who has never touched a programming language before this summer. I am helping write a R package for bioinformatics research. This is part of a much larger function that outputs a lot of distance data. But the previous code gave me the above list as an output. and all I want to do is return the wilcoxen scores for this part. (also from reading other answers I see a ton of for loop hate and I do have some really ugly loops in previous code so I don't want to put the entire thing online)

Comment: I am now looking to try and identify everything about the list I am using to try and shed light on the problem

Comment: Ok looking at it again its class is numeric. it doesn't have any levels. When I ran it as written above it worked so the problem is on my end I will update my question when I figure out which part is actually going wrong.

Comment: @Ahanna Rename your variable `ll <- list` then type  and edit your question using the result of `dput(head(ll))`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not as simple as converting to numeric, rather than an integer? Correct me if I misunderstood, but this seems to work:

```
wilcox.test(x=as.numeric(unlist(list)))
```

Gives output:

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  as.numeric(unlist(list))
V = 595, p-value = 1.164e-10
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `list <- ...` is not an R code. By reading your data as a big character using `scan`, you get a numeric vector.

```
ll <- scan(text='0.281097 0.245194 0.172255 0.136205 0.435323 0.431997 
           0.332863 0.371120 0.428497 0.414634 0.369541 0.303205 0.342573 
           0.328254 0.358234 0.364887 0.120683 0.118715 0.206876 0.387825 
           0.059059 0.075471 0.173021 0.359584 0.047235 0.083811 0.159509 
           0.361754 0.085833 0.162752 0.161182 0.362446 0.043862 0.035496',sep='')
```

Then applying `wilcox.test` is simply:

```
wilcox.test(ll)

Wilcoxon signed rank test
data:  ll
V = 595, p-value = 1.164e-10
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```